# Twig How can I print \n newlines

Tags: symfony, csv, twig

I have created the following template that gives an output as csv.

```
A;B;C
{% for a in as %}
{%  for b in a.b %}{{ a.a }};{{ b.b }};{{ b.c }};{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the output does noit have new lines. Do you have any idea how to print new lines (`\n`) to the template above?

Comment: Just press [`<enter>`](https://twigfiddle.com/ieqss9) between `;{{ b.c }};` and `{% endfor %}`

Comment: That worked can you put ti as a solution below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press <kbd>enter</kbd> between `;{{ b.c }};` and `{% endfor %}`

```
A;B;C
{% for a in as %}
{%  for b in a.b %}{{ a.a }};{{ b.b }};{{ b.c }};
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```